# appending extra character for html attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jstl

I have a requirement to add **#** followed by dynamic value. Please suggest how can i append **#** before dynamic value.
Below is my sample code:

```
 <c:forEach items="${myList}" var="myDataList">
    <li><a href="${myDataList.value}">click here</a></li>
 </c:forEach>
```

I want to add **#** followed by ${myDataList.value} for **href** attribute.
If ${myDataList.value} returns ABC it should assign #ABC to href attribute. Thanks.

Comment: Surely you would just have `<a href="#${myDataList.value}">`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<c:forEach items="${myList}" var="myDataList">
    <li><a href="#${myDataList.value}">click here</a></li>
 </c:forEach>
```

or URL encoded:

```
<c:forEach items="${myList}" var="myDataList">
    <li><a href="%23${myDataList.value}">click here</a></li>
 </c:forEach>
```